# Assembly 16-bit interrupts

Tags: assembly, x86

```
; another attempt to terminate program with Esc that hooks
; keyboard interrupt
    [org 0x100]
    jmp start
    oldisr: dd 0 ; space for saving old isr
; keyboard interrupt service routine
kbisr: push ax
    push es
    mov ax, 0xb800
    mov es, ax ; point es to video memory
    in al, 0x60 ; read a char from keyboard port
    cmp al, 0x2a ; is the key left shift
    jne nextcmp ; no, try next comparison
    mov byte [es:0], 'L' ; yes, print L at top left
    jmp nomatch ; leave interrupt routine
    nextcmp: cmp al, 0x36 ; is the key right shift
    jne nomatch ; no, leave interrupt routine
    mov byte [es:0], 'R' ; yes, print R at top left
    nomatch: ; mov al, 0x20
; out 0x20, al
    pop es
    pop ax
    jmp far [cs:oldisr] ; call the original ISR
; iret
start: xor ax, ax
    mov es, ax ; point es to IVT base
    mov ax, [es:9*4]
    mov [oldisr], ax ; save offset of old routine
    mov ax, [es:9*4+2]
    mov [oldisr+2], ax ; save segment of old routine
    cli ; disable interrupts
    mov word [es:9*4], kbisr ; store offset at n*4
    mov [es:9*4+2], cs ; store segment at n*4+2
    sti ; enable interrupts
l1: mov ah, 0 ; service 0 – get keystroke
    int 0x16 ; call BIOS keyboard service
    cmp al, 27 ; is the Esc key pressed
    jne l1 ; if no, check for next key
    mov ax, 0x4c00 ; terminate program
    int 0x21
```

I'm wonder that why we can only use cs:offset for the purpose to call oldIsr in this program. Why just **CS** ???

AT THIS LINE

```
jmp far [cs:oldisr] ; call the original ISR
```

WHAT is the purpose behind the it? 
Please explain it!!!

Comment: If an answer was the info you needed please consider **accepting** the answer. More on how and why of doing that here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside 16b real mode interrupt handler code you don't know the values of segment registers, they can be anything. Usually you can expect at least stack (`ss:sp`) to be reasonably valid and large enough to store return address and few bytes for handler, and also `cs` is fixed to the handler code, because in case of different `cs` value the CPU would execute some different instructions, not yours.

So to avoid hassle of storing old/unknown `ds`, setting up data segment of handler variables, and accessing them through `ds:` prefixes, then restoring `ds` back, it is easier to have the variable next to the code itself, and address it by `cs:oldisr`, as the value of `cs` is known to be what you need.

---

I will try to write it in more simple way:

`mov ax,[si]` is by default using `ds` (*1), i.e. it is actually doing `mov ax,[ds:si]`.

You can override the default by writing the segment register explicitly like `mov ax,[cs:si]`.

Physical memory address in 16b real mode is: segment_value*16+offset_value

When the code does enter your ISR handler, you do NOT know, what the running code had in `ds` or `es` at the moment of interrupt. It may point anywhere in the memory (NOT to your variables!).

But you know, that `cs` points to your handler instructions (otherwise CPU would execute instructions elsewhere, because CPU does execute next instruction from memory at `cs:ip`).

Just look how your handler has to preserve/set/restore `es`, that's example what you would have to do with `ds`, to be able to use the `ds`.

The `cs` is already preserved on stack, set to your code segment, and `IRET` (in old handler) will restore it.

---

1) The `bp` is using by default `ss`, the `stos/movs/cmps` are using by default both `ds` and `es`, and only the source `ds` can be overridden, the `es` for target is fixed.

Comment: Please can you explain it in more simple words ?

Comment: Thanks man. Got the point now. The point I was missing is that When the code does enter your ISR handler, you do NOT know, what the running code had in ds or es at the moment of interrupt. It may point anywhere in the memory (NOT to your variables!). But why is that so ?

Comment: uhm.. because the running code is using segment registers as it does wish? When you write non-interrupt 16b assembly code, you are free to change+use `ds` and `es` (and even `ss`, if `ss:sp` forms valid stack memory of reasonable size, or disable interrupts for the time the `ss:sp` is invalid). Keep in mind you have 1MiB of memory address space available (and in this era you know you *have* 1MiB of physical RAM available, as computers with only 300-600kiB are not manufactured for 30+ years), but 16b offset can cover only 64kiB, so code will need to change segment regs to access more memory.

Comment: @MUDASSIRNAYYERSHEIKH Maybe one more thing to note... the CPU registers are not per-process/executable, but they are like "super globals", per CPU core. So when ISR happens, you can see in register values which are used by some application code, right in the middle of doing something. If you would not correctly save/restore them, and modify them slightly, all the apps would start crashing, nothing would work correctly.

Comment: Thumbs up. for giving such explanation and for your time.

Comment: @MUDASSIRNAYYERSHEIKH you can do the "thumbs up" by accepting this answer as valid one, by clicking the accept button under the vote score of answer (on top of answer, left panel).